# How to utilise a driver for input from another driver?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I have to utilise a particular driver which does DMA and then map the memory of this DMA into multiple virtual devices that would handle read/write for these memory locations.
Basically separating the memory into multiple parts, each of which would be handled by a virtual driver to do its own thing.

My problem arises when I would need to access the main DMA driver from other drivers. Currently I can run a user-space program which can read/write to the memory but I have read from various places that using user-space methods of reading/writing to driver is frowned upon and not recommended for other drivers.

I do not have much experience writing drivers but know that many drivers in the kernel do talk to each other but cannot a proper lead to study further on how they do it.

Would anyone show me the direction to find the solution for this or give some examples where one driver would talk to another driver.

Code example :

Main driver that does the DMA that I would like to use

```
static const struct file_operations dma = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = char_sgdma_open,
    .release = char_sgdma_close,
    .write = char_sgdma_write,
    .read_iter = cdev_read_iter,
    ..
    ..
};
```

Driver that I need the above method's implementation to be used in. It would be
a simple char driver with read/write associated with one part of the main DMA

```
struct file_operations device1 = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open = device1_open,
    .read = device1_read,
    .write = device1_write,
    .release = device1_close,
};
```

Basically, I would like to use the methods from struct dma handling read/write inside the struct device1 without having to rewrite the entire thing each time for multiple devices that we would require.

The user-space program can just read/write to the main dma driver like a normal file.

Would it be really bad to just do the same read/write to the driver from another driver?

Would I have to reimplement the way DMA read/write works for each of these sub devices or is there a better way to just utilise it from the main dma driver?

Any ideas/tips/resources would be welcome.

Comment: Not every driver should represent  character device.

Comment: What does that mean? what would you recommend if not a char driver?